Unable to install tensorflow module on jupyter notebook
I tried installing tensorflow on jupyter notebook by using !pip install tensorflow but it gave this output: OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 1
----> 1 get_ipython().system('pip install tensorflow')
File /lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2653, in InteractiveShell.system_piped(self, cmd)
2648     raise OSError("Background processes not supported.")
2650 # we explicitly do NOT return the subprocess status code, because
2651 # a non-None value would trigger :func:sys.displayhook calls.
2652 # Instead, we store the exit_code in user_ns.
-> 2653 self.user_ns['_exit_code'] = system(self.var_expand(cmd, depth=1))
File /lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/utils/_process_emscripten.py:11, in system(cmd)
10 def system(cmd):
---> 11     raise OSError("Not available")
OSError: Not available
I tried using same command: !pip install tensorflow on another jupyter notebook account but it gave same output that it's not available

Possibly pip is not installed.

And in modern Jupyter you should be using %pip install, not the exclamation point. In 2019 the magic version of the pip install command was added to make installations from inside running notebooks work more reliably & conveniently. The The exclamation point  in conjunction with a pip install doesn't insure the installation is occurring in the same environment where the active kernel is running. The magic variation does. See more about modern %pip install command here. ...

 The second paragraph here goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues.  This is not to say that will solve your issue here. However, when you get your machine set up right you'll have a better experience using Jupyter going forward wherever you use it, if you start adapting current best practices and don't use outdated approaches.

I tried '%pip install tensorflow' and this was the output: ValueError: Can't find a pure Python 3 wheel for 'tensorflow'.
See: https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/faq.html#why-can-t-micropip-find-a-pure-python-wheel-for-a-package
You can use await micropip.install(..., keep_going=True) to get a list of all packages with missing wheels.  What do you suggest I do?
